I am stuck with my code. Trying to calculate Year over Year % change for Electric and Combustion counts in my dataset
I am trying to get percentage chngs YoY for both electric and combustion counts in my dataset for years 2000 and after.
I used CTEs. First one for simply getting the counts ordered by year ascending for both Electric and combustion counts.
The second one I tried to calculate yearly growth for both Electric and combustion counts
The query results in error:

The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET
or FOR XML is also specified.

Any help would be appreciated!
    WITH cte_EV_Comb_Counts AS (
    SELECT 
        year,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN fuel_type_1 = 'Electricity' AND year >= '2000' THEN 1 END) AS Electricity,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN fuel_type_1 <> 'Electricity' AND year >= '2000' THEN 1 END) AS Combustion
    FROM 
        fuel$
    WHERE 
        year >= '2000'
    GROUP BY 
        year
    ORDER BY 
        year ASC
),
cte_yearly_growth AS (
    SELECT 
        year, 
        LAG(Electricity, 1) OVER (ORDER BY year) AS Previous_Electricity,
        LAG(Combustion, 1) OVER (ORDER BY year) AS Previous_Combustion,
        (Electricity - LAG(Electricity, 1) OVER (ORDER BY year ASC)) / LAG(Electricity, 1) OVER (ORDER BY year ASC) * 100 AS yearly_growth_EV,
        (Combustion - LAG(Combustion, 1) OVER (ORDER BY year ASC)) / LAG(Combustion, 1) OVER (ORDER BY year ASC) * 100 AS yearly_growth_Comb
    FROM 
        cte_EV_Comb_Counts
)
SELECT 
    year,
    Electricity,
    Combustion,
    yearly_growth_EV,
    yearly_growth_Comb
FROM 
    cte_yearly_growth


Please show some sample data and the expected result

Why do you need ORDER BY in the 1st CTE?

Can the sample data be an image?

No, sample data and expected result as properly formatted text are expected. And simplify if possible, i.e. provide a [mcve]. And don't forget to add a tag for the dbms used.
